# how to get id of the visible middle element of jCarousel

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

please suggest how to get id of [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) middle element in case of infinite loop configuration?
[image: example]

Comment: Since they are all `<li>` elements inside the same `<ul>`, I guess the only way is to keep track of the number of clicks (left or right) and compute the position of the middle `<img>` element. Plus, they don't seem to have an explicit `id` attribute...

Comment: So you'll only show 3 items at a time, or is this going to be dynamic? Also, have you tried anything from your part?